# R: writing to disk using parallel

Tags: r, linux

It is possible to use the package `R.cache` with the package `parallel`.
I'm doing some computation that are very time comsuming and I would like to use a cache along with going parallel.

The the parrallel jobs are independent for each other. Yet I cannot load the R.cache package on the clusters.

```
library(parallel)
library(R.cache)

cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
clusterExport(cl,varlist = ls())
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(R.cache))

## Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
##   2 nodes produced errors; first error: there is no package called ‘R.cache’
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using? RRO (now Microsoft R) uses SIMD and multi-core operations and uses the disk to process more data than what fits in memory.

Comment: I'm using the one that is free. R is a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics.

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you pick a permanent or temporary directory for `R.chache`?

Comment: Yes I did. Do you think it is a problem?

Comment: *Both* are open source, free and cross platform. One is just 7 times faster than the other on an i7 (running svd). This isn't idle talk. `parallel` and any tool that uses multiple processes has a very high overhead compared to threading. And SIMD operations means you can process 4 floats in a single cycle per core instead of one.

Comment: Did you forget to install `R.cache`? See your error message.

Comment: @Christoph I did not as when I use `library(R.cache)` directly it works fine.

Comment: In my case it works for `version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)`. I don't get your point about installation. What does `is.installed <- function(mypkg) is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])` and
`is.installed("R.cache")` give?

Comment: @Christoph you are right. I change the .libPaths() in the main code when I exported R.cache to the library it didn't find it.  clusterEvalQ(cl, `library(R.cache),lib.loc='/path')` did the job. I messed up with the library location. Sorry for the trouble.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing particular about `R.cache` here.  You need to make sure `R.cache` is installed on each of the compute nodes.

And yes, `R.cache` works and is designed to work on concurrent systems.  See also https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.cache/issues/18

(I'm the author of `R.cache`).

Comment: many thanks to you. R.cache really helps. I made a stupid mistake about my libpaths.